# Is it possible to handle a file to another App without displaying the Share Screen in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

I've never written any code with **Objective-C** and I'm as lost as you can be.

My App is in **React Native** but I couldn't find a way to achieve this so I had to start to search for a solution using Native Code.

What I basically need to do is taking a file I downloaded in my app's sandbox and open it in other app (**PowerPoint**) without actually showing the **Share Screen Modal** where the user selects the other App.

I know that when "Sharing" the file is copied into the PowerPoint's folder but I'm not sure if I'm able to do this kind of actions.

I was told to use this -> `UIDocumentInteractionController` but like I said, I'm not sure if it allows me to do that.

Any suggestion is welcome !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Actually if the app can be "downloaded", that suggests it is on the network somewhere. You might be able to hand PowerPoint a deep link or universal link that tells _it_ to open the document from the network. But that depends on whether PowerPoint accepts that sort of thing.

Comment: @matt I tried so by using the link on the network and PowerPoint says "Unsupported server location" and, when using the path where the file was downloaded, it opens like a blank session. (Not sure if its because its in my App's sandbox). 
If I actually use the share screen it does it perfectly.

Comment: Can you think of any app on your phone now that behaves the way you describe — that somehow makes another app open a document from it, without passing thru the user and the share sheet?